# Objective-c method without return type

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is it correct to write objective-c method like this

```
-methodA: (NSString *)str // without return type 
{
    return @"test";
}
```

Above method is working fine for me.
Is `-methodA: (NSString *)str`  same as `-(id)methodA: (NSString *)str`?
I am using `Mac 10.5 os x` sdk.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To answer your question, from "The Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language":

> If a return or argument type isn’t explicitly declared, it’s assumed to be the default type for methods and messages — an `id`.

So `- methodA:(NSString *)str` is valid and the same as `- (id)methodA:(NSString *)str`.

However having said that it is certainly unusual coding practice and not to be encouraged - type the extra four characters!

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void) methodA (NSString *)str //always start a methodod name lower case
{
  return;  //If you do not return anything then there is nothing to return. 
}
```

`(id)` is different from `(void)`. You will have to return somthing here. `id` represents an object of any type. Only `void` represents 'nothing'.

Comment: Is -MethodA: (NSString *)str same as -(id)MethodA: (NSString *)str?

Comment: Well, yes. (id) is the default return type if none is given.

Answer (score 3):

I changed -init in my app:

```
-init
{
    ...
    return self;
}
```

and compiler did not show any warning, and if I change -init like that:

```
-(int)init
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

compiler shows warning about expected type, so I could say -init and -(id)init are the same methods, since I did not even know that compiler would pass this syntax and since checking language's features like that is bad practice :). I will read Apple's docs about Objective-C and try to find out something about that. Thanks for nice question :)

EDIT:

wow, you can read docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-SW1), chapter Class Interface. (void), (NSObject*) and etc are only casts. Quote: "Method return types are declared using the standard C syntax for casting one type to another". And another quote: "If a return or parameter type isn’t explicitly declared, it’s assumed to be the default type for methods and messages—an id".

Comment: just because the *syntax* used is the same as casts it does not mean the *semantics* are those of a cast... Values of different types are handled differently by cpus and compilers - the return type tells the compiler how a method should return its result (on the stack, in a register, how large it is, etc.), and how a method call should receive the value - it is not a cast!

Comment: I meant that removing this "casts" will work same as with them in runtime (maybe, not almost same, as compiler could optimize code, but returning type and arguments' type will be the same), but thanks for clarifiyng!

Answer (score 3):

It is allowed, as language specification states

> If a return or parameter type isn’t explicitly declared, it’s assumed to be the default type for methods and messages—an `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Well if it compiles and it operates as you expect, then it works. But I wouldn't say that it's good practice.

If I'd had to guess, I would have assumed that your method would return nothing. So although "correct" it's misleading.

If you really do want to return an object of any type, would the extra four characters hurt? If it really returns nothing, set a return type of `void`. Pleasing the compiler is easy but not the whole story.

Answer (score 1):

Even if it compiles it's not correct. It makes life slightly harder for other developers, including your future self.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
- (void)methodA:(NSString *)str 
{
  //non returning method;
}
```

---

```
- (NSString *)methodA:(NSString *)str 
{
  return str;  //returning method;
}
```