# Are argument types optional for methods?

Tags: objective-c

I came across this unusual bit of Objective-C today which, to my suprise, compiles without fail and outputs "hi":

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyObject : NSObject

- (NSString *)method:param;

@end

@implementation MyObject

- (NSString *)method:param
{
    return param;
}

@end

int main() {
    MyObject * m = [MyObject new];
    NSLog(@"%@", [m method:@"hi"]);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile command:

```
# clang version: clang-900.0.37
clang test.m -fobjc-arc -o test
```

`method` has a single argument, `param`, but I did not explicitly give a type. I can't seem to find any documentation on this? What's going on?

Comment: Return and argument types default to `id`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12260869/1187415, https://stackoverflow.com/q/20091717/1187415.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I figured, but just couldn't find the documentation on it. Thanks @Martin R

Comment: Mostly because this is an ancient left-over from the early days of Objective-C (long before Apple picked it up). It's one of those things that technically works and is legal but you should never do. (Though as noted in Martin's linked answers, it is documented. Just never, ever do this.)

Comment: @RobNapier It actually predates NeXT, IIRC, and NeXT adopted it in the "chaining model" of pre-OpenStep AppKit.

Answer (score 1):

I've been unable to find any official docs on this, but in my testing this is indistinguishable from the param being a generic `id` type.